# JNI DeleteLocalRef Clarification

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

Question 1:

```
jstring jstrKey;
for(int i=1;i<=1000;++i) {
    LPWSTR strKey = L"string";
    jstrKey = env->NewString((jchar *)strKey, wcslen(strKey));
}
env->DeleteLocalRef(jstrKey);
```

Question 2:

```
for(int i=1;i<=1000++i) {
    LPWSTR strKey = L"string";
    jstring jstrKey = env->NewString((jchar *)strKey, wcslen(strKey));
    env->DeleteLocalRef(jstrKey);
}
```

Am i using DeleteLocalRef properly in both questions?

Especially in Question 1, I am deleting local ref after the loop. I think that is correct, and need not call deletelocalref inside the loop since I am not creating any new local ref.

**So no issues with respect to usage of `DeleteLocalRef` right?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to release jstring in a loop correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519116/how-to-release-jstring-in-a-loop-correctly)

Comment: Hi Alex,
I think i need not release the strings allocated in loop. They will be automatically GCed right? (i didnt call GetStringChars / GetStringUTFChars, if i call them only i need to ReleaseStringchars)
my question is about DeleteLocalRef usage.

Comment: Hi @Praveen Kumar, According to the documentation, local references become invalid when the execution returns from the native method in which the local reference is created.  So in order to correctly answer you question, we need to know what you do with the jstring and how the function that your sample code resides in is called.  Under most circumstances, you don't need to explicitly call DeleteLocalRef.

Comment: @AlexBarker To be explicit, the circumstances where you don't need to to call `DeleteLocalRef` are those where you wouldn't run out.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In both cases you should call `DeleteLocalRef()` inside the loop because each `NewString()` crerates a new local ref.

Local references will be discarded by JNI on return from a native method, but this process has nothing to do with Java garbage collection. Usually, we don't need to worry about local references. But the local ref table is usually quite small, therefore we must discard unused references which are created on a significantly long loop.

Comment: Thanks Alex Cohn, and another doubt, in both cases i need not call RelaseStringChars right? (since i didnt call GetStringChars anywhere..)

Comment: absolutely. *Release* is paired with *Get*; note that for every **Get** flavor (`GetStringChars()`, `GetStringUTFChars()`, `GetStringCritical()`, etc.) you must use the corresponding **ReleaseXXX()**. `GetStringLength()` and such do not expect **Release**.

Answer (score 2):

The first loop is certainly not *correct,* but the incorrectness may be *benign.* It isn't the same thing.