# JNI accessing array of array

Tags: java, c, arrays, multidimensional-array, java-native-interface

I am trying to write a benchmark for different sorting algorithms in java, for that I wanted to explore the world of JNI.
I am trying to sort a set of int arrays which are contained in an array.
This is my Java header:

```
public static native void sort(int[][] c);
```

I used javah to generate this C header for it:

`JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_jku_ssw_prsw2_ue6_jni_JNISorter_sort (JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jobjectArray objArr`)

Then I try to get the length of the array with

```
jsize len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, objArr);
```

but from here I'm kinda stuck, I can get a jobject element from this array using GetObjectArrayElement but how do I procceed from there to get a jint array which I can then finally sort?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you know the `jobject` you retrieve is actually an `int[]`, you can safely cast it to a `jintArray` and then go from there e.g.:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Main_sort(JNIEnv *env, jclass _, jobjectArray objArr) {
    jsize len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, objArr);

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        jintArray arr = (jintArray) (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, objArr, i);
        jsize innerLen = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, arr);
        jint* vals = (*env)->GetIntArrayElements(env, arr, NULL);            

        /* make changes to 'vals' */

        (*env)->ReleaseIntArrayElements(env, arr, vals, JNI_COMMIT);
        (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tha'ts not a cast, it is a function call.

Comment: @EJP What do you mean? The `jintArray arr = (jintArray) ...` uses a cast.

Comment: You probably should add a `( *env )->DeleteLocalRef( env, arr );` call at the end of your `for` loop.  With a large object array, you might fill the local reference table.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289724/jni-deletelocalref-clarification